# Project Deployment AI

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, deployment, artificial-intelligence

i have this project called AIOS CHAT, i put everything and on local it works very well, but when i try to upload all files to vercel i got error page not loading just vercel error/

here is my screenshot of my files if someone can tell me what to deploy where, for free like onrender vercel or other things i just want to test on internet then i will buy host and edit everything

[image: here is my files]

How to deploy this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be to deploy you should make the build file which can be made easily.

For React:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: when i upload that to netlify i got error , page not showing if you have time to help you can dm me on discord so i can share : timur#7827